# How to limit hyphenation in a multicol environment?

Tags: hyphenation, multicol, microtype

I have a LaTeX document (compiling with `pdflatex`), with the `multicols` and `microtype` package enabled.

The document is using two cols using the `\begin{multicols}{2} ...\end{multicols}` environment.

`microtype` already does a great job with kerning. But still I have quite a lot of 
hyphenated words. Often times I have three or even more hyphenated 'lines' in a row.

Is there a way to add a penalty in LaTeX, to only have two hyphenated 'lines' in a row?

Answer (score 2):

Since you did not post MWE, just a general advice

```
\sloppy
\doublehyphendemerits=10000
```

sometimes helps.  Unfortunately there is no primitive `\triplehyphendemerits`, which would help in your case.

Comment: Isn't `\doublehyphendemerits=10000` already the default in (plain) TeX?

Comment: It is in plain and latex.  However, without MWE I cannot be sure that some package did not change it at some point...

Comment: Declaring `\sloppy` is like jumping out of the frying pan into the fire. Many hyphens may give a bad result, with `\sloppy` you're certain to get it. If the columns are narrow, hyphens are a necessary evil.

Comment: I agree with you about the problem caused by the lack of an MWE. Some class files, e.g., suftesi.cls and kluwer.cls, set the `\doublehyphendemerits` parameter to 100000 and 640000, respectively. On the other hand, the widely-used apa.cls sets this parameter to a fairly permissive 5000. Makes me wonder just how important this parameter is in practice...

Comment: @egreg: I agree.  Actually for narrow columns `\raggedright` might be the best (or the least bad) solution.

Comment: It all depends on how narrow are the columns. For instance, the article class widens the total width in two column format and the result is quite decent.

Comment: @Mico Demerits are in units of "badness squared", so the value should be pretty high (100000 is high) in order to give visible results. The difference between 5000 and 10000 is not that significant, then.